# Morris.js chart in Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, morris.js

I have have a Rails 4 application that calls an Ajax and shows results in a Bootstrap modal. I get an error when I try to render a Morris.js chart in the modal. What I get instead of a chart looks like this:

[image: Modal]

Could you please give me a pointer where to find a solution? I'm using Turbolinks.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to redraw the graph after loading the modal with `shown.bs.modal`

Or you can delay the drawing of the graph:

```
  setTimeout( function(){
     Morris.Area({...})
  },1200);
```